# I find an item in a WPF ListBox by typing

Tags: wpf, listbox

Hi would like find an item in listbox by typing, I find many examples, but I think something I do bad.

I bind to the listbox my  dictionary. Friend is my class, it look like this:

```
 [JsonObject]
    [Export]
    public class Friend
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Nick;
        }

        [JsonProperty("idUser")]
        public string IdUser { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nick")]
        public string Nick { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sefNick")]
        public string SefNick { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isFriend")]
        public bool IsFriend { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public int Status { get; set; }

    }
```

I have own data template on listbox here is it:

```
 <Style x:Key="friendsListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="RootLayout">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Margin="4,4,4,2" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Image.Source >
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource imageConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Value.ProfilePhoto"></Binding>
                                    <Binding Path="Value.Status"></Binding>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                        <Grid  Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock 
                                   Text="{Binding Value.Nick}" 
                                   Margin="2,2,2,2" 
                                   FontSize="13" 
                                   FontWeight="Medium"
                                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock  
                                   Text="{Binding Value.BlockQuote}"
                                   FontSize="11" 
                                   FontWeight="Normal" 
                                   Foreground="DarkGray"
                                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock  
                                   Text="{Binding Value.Status,Converter={StaticResource statusConverter}}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource StatusStyle}"
                                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" >
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="RootLayout">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.25" ScaleY="1.25" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
```

I apply this template on listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="Friends" 
         SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedFriendsIndex,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFriend, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Style="{DynamicResource friendsListStyle}"
         IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Nick"
</ListBox>
```

I enable text search I want search by Nick, Nick is string property of Friend class:

```
IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Nick"
```

But it doesn’t works. I examples I find only that you must enable IsTextSearchEnabled and set TextSearch.TextPath on string property of item object.

What I do bad. Thank for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the ItemsSource of the `ListBox` a collection of Friend, like `ObservableCollection<Friend>`?
In that case you shouldn't use `Value.` in the Bindings like `Text="{Binding Value.Nick}"` etc. It should just be `Text="{Binding Nick}"`. Otherwise, if the ItemsSource is indeed something else, where `Nick` is located in a Property called Value then you must take that into account when setting `TextSearch.TextPath`, so `TextSearch.TextPath="Value.Nick"`. Other than that, the TextSearch is working just fine.